# How to deal with class instances in Jena?

Tags: instance, jena, ontology, jena-rules

In an ontology, suppose we have a class named "function" it has two instances "func1" and "func2" and suppose that the class has a data property "d".

**My first problem is:** how can I create individuals corresponding to either "func1" or "func2" ?

**My second problem is :** In the inference, with Jena rules, I want to check if individuals created for "func1" have "d" greater than some value and if individuals created for "func2" have "d" greater than another value.

I already know how to work with classes, properties and individuals but when I got to the part having instances I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Jena Library has no support for instances, which means that you can't use `getInstance()` and create individuals for that instance.

Instead of having instances `func1` and `func2`, you can make them as subclasses for the class `function`. This way, you can use `getOntClass()` and `createIndividual()` or `getIndividual()` as usual.